# How to flatten a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I got a dataframe that looks like this:
[Original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzhdZ.png)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                  '1': [123,145,293,403],
                  '2': [402,103,242,757],
                  '3': [3.121,4.55,0,9.32],
                  '4': ['3T', '4B', '400B', '400T']})
```

and I need to transform that DataFrame so it looks something like this:

| a_1 | a_2 | a_3 | a_4 | b_1 | b_2 | b_3 | b_4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 402 | 3.121 | 3T | 145 | 103 | 4.555 | 4B | ... |

Anyone knows how to do it with pandas?

Comment: Please paste the original data as text in the question.

Comment: Added the data as text @Cyttorak

Comment: Reformat your question.i.e. "how to flatten a dataframe". More people will be able to help you.  I can't help now but I am pretty sure you should read the documentation about pivot tables as it looks to be the way to go. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html

Answer (score 4):

you can use `stack()` then `transpose`

```
s = df.set_index('0').stack()
s.index = [f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in s.index]

s.to_frame('').T
```

---

```
  a_1  a_2    a_3 a_4  b_1  b_2   b_3 b_4  c_1  c_2 c_3   c_4  d_1  d_2   d_3  \
  123  402  3.121  3T  145  103  4.55  4B  293  242   0  400B  403  757  9.32   

   d_4  
  400T
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pivot your dataframe and then rename and sort its columns:

```
tmp = df.assign(ix=0).pivot('ix', '0', list('1234'))
result = tmp.set_axis(['{1}_{0}'.format(*i) for i in tmp.columns], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

With your data it gives as expected:

```
   a_1  a_2    a_3 a_4  b_1  b_2   b_3  ...  c_2  c_3   c_4  d_1  d_2   d_3   d_4
0  123  402  3.121  3T  145  103  4.55  ...  242  0.0  400B  403  757  9.32  400T

[1 rows x 16 columns]
```